# (raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'status' )in got this error when i want to add new row in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

im trying to create candle plot. i want to add some data in a row  but i got this error

> in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'status'

code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import yfinance as yf
import datetime


start = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)

msft = yf.download('MSFT', start= start, end=end)

def in_de(c, o):
    if c < o :
        value = 'increase'
    elif c > o :
        value = 'decrease'
    else:
        value = 'Eqal'
    
    return value


plot = figure(x_axis_type = 'datetime', width = 800, height = 400)
msft["Status"] = [in_de(c,o) for c, o in zip (msft.Close,msft.Open)]
msft["Middle"] = (msft.Open + msft.Close)/2
msft["Height"] = abs(msft.Close - msft.Open)





print(msft)
```

Comment: Code above runs with no issue for me, you will need to provide more information, e.g. all relevant package versions You should *always* specify package versions up front in any OSS question. You should also provide the *entire* backtrace, not just one line. That error about `get_loc` looks like it is coming from Pandas, not Bokeh, but it's impossible to say anything with just that one line.